# Create custom objects in Python, to hold only data

Tags: python

I am planning to use a custom datatype for loading and saving data on disk. This will ease my work since I can access each piece of info with the dot notation.

I never did something similar in Python, so I did some research and found that Python has a struct module. Although, all that I would like to do is to have an object that contain data. Would this be OK?

```
class myobj(object):
    a=None
    b=None
    c=None

    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a=a
        self.b=b
        self.c=c
```

Which I would use it in this way:

```
mydict = defaultdict(myobj)
mylist = (item1, item2, item3)

for val in mylist:    
    myobj.a = 12
    myobj.b = "hello"
    myobj.c = True

    mydict[val] = myobj
```

Is this correct or am I doing it wrong? I would like to do it in a proper Python way.

Comment: If you're storing data, I would recommend `pickle`. It's store many python data types.

Comment: You have quite a few mistakes in the code. First dont use list as a variable name. Second, your __init__ is missing self. third, all your myobj are same, as you use class variables, not instance ones. Could you clarify what you want to do, appart from keeping data on the disk.

Comment: I'd recommend against using pickle, just in case class definitions (names, structure, etc.) change from under you. Might I suggest using json encoding/decoding?

Comment: Go through the [classes](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/classes.html) documentation first. Then, if you're storing "simple" data like your example, look at [json.dumps](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/json.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on my comment above, I changed your code example, so that it is "more" OK now.

```
class myobj(object):

    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a=a
        self.b=b
        self.c=c

mydict = {}
a_list = [1, 2, 3]

for val in a_list:
    mydict[val] = myobj(12, "hello", True)
```

It does not save anything on the disk yet, but its good start. If you could clarify what and how you want to store the object, or what kind of data, than maybe I could help better.

ALternative version:

```
class myobj(object):

    def __init__(self, a=0, b="", c=False):
        self.a=a
        self.b=b
        self.c=c

mydict = {}
a_list = [1, 2, 3]

for val in a_list:
    an_myobj = myobj()

    an_myobj.a = 12
    an_myobj.b = "hello"
    an_myobj.c = True

    mydict[val] = an_myobj
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I made corrections in the question. IS there a way to use the object without pass the parameters, and instead assign them with dot notation? I may get data from different sources, and would rather assign them via dot notation and then just pass myobj to the dictionary. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, but you would have to design myobj differently. As it is now, you cant.

Comment: This is what I am aiming for; as in my example in the question. The type of data that I will store in the custom object is mainly int, strings and bool; it may come from different sources, and that's why I would rather have the dot notation for practical reasons

Comment: If so, than you can declare a,b,c with default arguments. Please see amended answer.

Comment: Much appreciated; this solve my problem. I am planning to use pickle to save this custom object, so I am good to go. Thanks!